# Enable logging in PostgreSQL for only a particular table

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I would like to know whether it is possible to enable logging in PostgreSQL for only a particular table (i.e. logging with table-level granularity)?

Currently the logs are being printed in the following way. If we enable complete logging like this, the allocated HDD space will be eaten through in less than 30 mins.

```
GMT_jbpm_LOG:  00000: duration: 0.104 ms  bind <unnamed>: select instances0_.PROCESSINSTANCE_ as PROCESSI4_1_, instances0_.ID_ as ID1_1_, instances0_.NAME_ as NAME6_1_, instances0_.ID_ as ID1_54_0_, instances0_.VERSION_ as VERSION3_54_0_, instances0_.PROCESSINSTANCE_ as PROCESSI4_54_0_, instances0_.TASKMGMTDEFINITION_ as TASKMGMT5_54_0_, instances0_.CLASS_ as CLASS2_54_0_ from JBPM_MODULEINSTANCE instances0_ where instances0_.PROCESSINSTANCE_=$1
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_jbpm_DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '9646163'
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_jbpm_LOCATION:  exec_bind_message, postgres.c:1784
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_amq_LOG:  00000: duration: 0.023 ms
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_amq_LOCATION:  exec_execute_message, postgres.c:1988
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_jbpm_LOG:  00000: execute <unnamed>: select instances0_.PROCESSINSTANCE_ as PROCESSI4_1_, instances0_.ID_ as ID1_1_, instances0_.NAME_ as NAME6_1_, instances0_.ID_ as ID1_54_0_, instances0_.VERSION_ as VERSION3_54_0_, instances0_.PROCESSINSTANCE_ as PROCESSI4_54_0_, instances0_.TASKMGMTDEFINITION_ as TASKMGMT5_54_0_, instances0_.CLASS_ as CLASS2_54_0_ from JBPM_MODULEINSTANCE instances0_ where instances0_.PROCESSINSTANCE_=$1
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_jbpm_DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '9646163'
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_jbpm_LOCATION:  exec_execute_message, postgres.c:1918
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_jbpm_LOG:  00000: duration: 0.053 ms
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_jbpm_LOCATION:  exec_execute_message, postgres.c:1988
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_bnw_LOG:  00000: duration: 0.068 ms  parse <unnamed>: select workflowde0_.workflow_definition_id as workflow1_14_0_, workflowde0_.created as created14_0_, workflowde0_.deleted as deleted14_0_, workflowde0_.name as name14_0_, workflowde0_.version as version14_0_, workflowde0_.workspace_id as workspace6_14_0_ from workflow_definition workflowde0_ where workflowde0_.workflow_definition_id=$1
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_bnw_LOCATION:  exec_parse_message, postgres.c:1367
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_bnw_LOG:  00000: duration: 0.059 ms  parse <unnamed>: update worker set created=$1, deleted=$2, name=$3, full_name=$4, worker_type=$5, max_jobs_in_progress=$6, max_jobs_queued=$7, jobs_queued=$8, workspace_id=$9 where worker_id=$10
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_bnw_LOCATION:  exec_parse_message, postgres.c:1367
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_bnw_LOG:  00000: duration: 0.077 ms  bind <unnamed>: select workflowde0_.workflow_definition_id as workflow1_14_0_, workflowde0_.created as created14_0_, workflowde0_.deleted as deleted14_0_, workflowde0_.name as name14_0_, workflowde0_.version as version14_0_, workflowde0_.workspace_id as workspace6_14_0_ from workflow_definition workflowde0_ where workflowde0_.workflow_definition_id=$1
2013-03-27 09:42:09.039 GMT_bnw_DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '7089580'
```

What I'd like to do is enable logging for my table named `worker` table, however avoid logging events regarding any of the other tables in my database.

To reiterate - is there any way in PostgreSQL to log information for only a particular Table?

```
UPDATE worker SET created=$1, deleted=$2, name=$3;
```

Answer (score 7):

The only way to do table-level granularity of logging in PostgreSQL is to use triggers. You might find the [audit trigger](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) in the PostgreSQL wiki to be informative. If all you want is to log the statement text, a statement-level trigger that does a `RAISE NOTICE` (or some lower log level) with the statement text should suffice.

You *can* just `SET log_statement = 'all'` via SQL before accessing the table, but I suspect this isn't what you want.

Alternately, use a dedicated database or dedicated user and `SET` the parameter on the user or database. eg:

```
ALTER USER my_queue_user SET log_statement = 'all';
```

or:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET log_statement = 'all';
```

Note that the user can just override these with a `SET` or `SET LOCAL`, so they are *not* suitable for auditing.